# Type error related to date conversion updating a table in a Postgres folder

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following a data import in a Postgres database I run a function to normalise some of the data that has come in from an ODBC source. One field is a Date, but it is coming in as a varchar and for some rows it is null so when I try to convert it to a date type it fails. I realised that doesn't matter too much as the data is only used for display, but I need it to be in a useful format, so I found the following SQL:

```
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "VisitDate" =  to_char( DATE("VisitDate"), 'DD Mon YYYY' )  WHERE "VisitDate" <> '';
```

This works if I run it directly in the SQL browser, but when I execute the function it says this:

```
ERROR:  table row type and query-specified row type do not match
DETAIL:  Table has type character varying at ordinal position 6, but query expects text.
```

As far as I can tell, this is because the `to_char()` function returns text, but the field is a varchar ( and given the content it is logical for it to be ) so I thought maybe I could do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE "MyTable" ALTER "VisitDate" TYPE "text";
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "VisitDate" =  to_char( DATE("VisitDate"), 'DD Mon YYYY' )  WHERE "VisitDate" <> '';
ALTER TABLE "MyTable" ALTER "VisitDate" TYPE varchar(12);
```

Only of course, that doesn't work in a function because - as I understand it - Postgres runs the whole thing in a single transaction so the ALTER instruction isn't happening before the UPDATE so the same error arises.

If I try to use `varchar( to_char( ...etc ))` it just complains about the contents of the varchar function.

Following a comment below I tried having only that line in the function and it succeeds, if I have all the table alteration statements in the function it succeeds, if I have both it fails. A basic form of the function is this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION at_ebc_alterscorescolumns() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
ALTER TABLE "MyTable" ALTER "Postcode" TYPE varchar(10);
UPDATE "MyTable" SET "VisitDate" =  to_char( DATE("VisitDate"), 'DD Mon YYYY' )  WHERE "VisitDate" <> '';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

This leads me to wonder whether it is simply the case that it is not possible to alter a table and change the data in a single function.

My question is: How can I change the formatting of the field without causing this error?

Comment: The varchar versus text hypothesis is not very plausible and it's an unusual error message. You say it runs fine inside a SQL browser, but not when you "execute the function". What function? And what PG version?

Comment: If you want it to be a date, why not `ALTER TABLE "MyTable" ALTER "VisitDate" TYPE date USING "VisitDate"::date;` or whatever conversion is needed?

Comment: @DanielVérité - The line is in a function that also alters the format of a couple of other fields in the database. So when I execute the function it throws an error message in that line, when I execute the line alone it doesn't. When I execute the function without that line it runs correctly. Having tested it further I now see that when I execute the function with that line alone, it runs correctly, so I need to edit the question slightly.

Comment: @kgrittn Because some of the records are empty a direct type conversion fails.

Comment: The suggestion works if there are NULLs.  By "empty", do you mean that you have empty strings? Using a "magic value" like that to indicate "unknown" or "not applicable" will cause you no end of grief. I recommend that you update the column to NULL where it is = '', and then convert the column to a date.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could save a pass over the table: `ALTER TABLE "MyTable" ALTER "VisitDate" TYPE date USING NULLIF('', "VisitDate"::date);`

Comment: @kgrittn I did mean '' by Empty - perils of importing from a CSV file using ODBC. It didn't matter for the data as it's never used as a date, but that is a really good tip for the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the error with PG 8.4 when doing this:

```
create table foo(somedate text);

create function alter_foo() returns void as
$$
alter table foo alter somedate type varchar(10);
update foo set somedate = to_char(date(somedate),'DD Mon YYYY' );
$$
language sql;

select alter_foo();
```

The function call fails with this message:

> ERROR:  table row type and query-specified row type do not match
>   DETAIL:  Table has type character varying at ordinal position 1, but
>   query expects text. CONTEXT:  SQL function "alter_foo" statement 2

The easy work-around is to choose the `plpgsql` language instead of the `sql` language. The former is procedural while the latter is more suited to one-liners and stuff that is candidate for automatic inlining.
I guess the sql language processor somehow pre-parses the queries in such a way that it gets confused if the datatypes are changed during the execution of the function.

Anyway if you declare it like this:

```
create function alter_foo() returns void as
$$
 begin
   alter table foo alter somedate type varchar(10);
   update foo set somedate = to_char(date(somedate),'DD Mon YYYY' );
 end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

then it appears to work as intended.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem, but when I tried to change my function to PLPGSQL it choked with a Syntax Error on my `ALTER` statement ( specifically on the field name ) which seemed odd but I figured maybe Plpgsql wasn't made for table modifications. I will experiment further.